# Reset value in Firestore automatically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app manages some properties and theirs monthly rents. The user (or the landlord) has the option to select this day and also confirm the payment by the tenant. So base on this, I can display a message saying "X days late payment", "Payment day" or simply nothing.

Until here is fine, but how can I reset this payment automatically?

I guess I could use Firebase functions for this (I've never done any) and reset the `rent_paid` value to false the first day on every month, but how can we detect the user timezone? I guess we can get this value when the user logs in but not sure how to detect this on the server function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Scheduled Function on a which triggers on the first day of the month, however, the issue here is the time zone. You would need to have a way to distinguish the user timezone, you can do this as you mention when they log in and storing it in Firebase, of you could create a subcollection of all users separated by timezone so that you can reset them in a batch.

You can find the guide of the scheduled functions over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), however, the way to reset the user's information would be up to you and your schema.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: I think the first issue I found is that I'd need to upgrade my account. Thanks but I'll leave this for now until I need a bigger plan